# add new values to a file content in linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed

**Have** 2 files (fileA, FileB)

**FileA**

```
015638|00001059
015639|00001059
015640|00001059
015644|00001158
015645|00005795
015646|00000721
015648|00003804
015649|00005795
```

FileB

```
05052015
```

**Want** (Note: The last value is simply today's date)

```
015638|00001059|05052015|03312015
015639|00001059|05052015|03312015
015640|00001059|05052015|03312015
015644|00001158|05052015|03312015
015645|00005795|05052015|03312015
015646|00000721|05052015|03312015
015648|00003804|05052015|03312015
015649|00005795|05052015|03312015
```

I have a code which works but a little bit surprise why having a . before $ (in the sed statement) got it to work.

```
 sed "s/.$/|$(cat FileB)|$(date +"%m%d%Y")/" FileA
```

Can anyone explain why it worked? I'm also open to other solutions besides sed statement. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the other answer, it is not working correctly as it is removing the last character of each line in FileA.

However, removing the `.` will get you the desired result:

```
sed "s/$/|$(cat FileB)|$(date +"%m%d%Y")/" FileA
```

That is, replace the `line end` (`$`) with the content of `FileB` (file contains only 1 line) and `date` delimited by `|`.

Comment: Thanks.That's what I figured the correct code should be. File A had some non-printable characters in it upon investigation.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone explain why it worked?

I didn't work. That dot(`.`) matches the last character, and as you replacing, that character will be removed:

```
015638|0000105|05052015|03312015
015639|0000105|05052015|03312015
...
              ^oops
```

Comment: true IF last character is what you see (not a space character for example) but not sur, the (copied) sample could not be safe on this kind of point unless specificaly said by author.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "s/[^0-9]*$/|$(head -1 FileB)|$(date +"%m%d%Y")/" FileA
```

is maybe more secure and in the way of this code you catch
- remove any non digit last char (space, tab, ...)
- take 1 line of the FileB (avoid a erroneuous multiline) but it's optionnal, especialy if you ensure a mono line by creating the file yourself for the purpose